# Content Script not working for some reason

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I am trying to use a content script on my website but for some reason it isnt working

Here is my manifest.json:

```
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "TabToCal",
    "description": "Extension used to save a tab in calendar, for a later consultation.",
    "version": "1.1",
    "permissions": [
        "tabs"
    ],
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": ["*://*.tabtocallapi.herokuapp.com/*"],
        "js": ["contentscript.js"]
    }],

    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "login.html"
    }
```

Here is my contentscript.js:

```
console.log("test");

var greeting = "hello, ";
var button = document.getElementById("mybutton");
button.person_name = "Oscar";
button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    alert(greeting + button.person_name + ".");
}, false);
```

None of these are running any reason why?

It also is not appearing in the content script section

Comment: Your manifest looks fine. Make sure extension is enabled and that you are in at an address that matches "*://*.tabtocallapi.herokuapp.com/*"

Comment: I am on https://tabtocallapi.herokuapp.com/login and I have the extension added on chrome, but still nothing happens any way to fix it?

Comment: Please read https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

never mind had to remove and re-add the extension in my extensions for some reason it wasn't auto-updating.